# div element is not being displayed even though the element is present

Tags: html, css

I want to build a section like this:

[image]

So, I built a `div` having red color and got an image and kept both these elements inside another div. But for some reason the red div doesn't display on the screen, however it is present in the page, as I can see it using the chrome developer tools

Also, when I position the `img` as `absolute`, the height and width of the images becomes 0.

How do I avoid this?

This is my HTML and CSS code:

```css
/* Why choose Section */

#Why_choose{
  height: 100%;
  background: #141414;
}

.wrap_Container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.wrap_Container div{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#Why_choose h1{
  color: white;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

#Why_choose h2{
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#Why_choose p{
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  width: 60%;
}

#Why_choose img{
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
}

.Why_heading{
  position: relative;
  height: 25vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Why_heading h1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
}

.big-box{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#Why_choose .small-red-box{
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<section id="Why_choose">
    <div class="Why_heading"> 
      <h1>Why choose Snap Smile Veneers?</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap_Container">

      <div class="invisible">
        <div class="big-box">
          <div class="small-red-box"></div>
          <img src="images/invisible.png">
        </div>
        <h2>we invisible</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
          dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="comfortable">
        <div class="big-box">
          <div class="small-red-box"></div>
          <img src="images/comfortable.png">
        </div>
        <h2>we comfortable</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
          dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="workHome">
        <div class="big-box">
          <div class="small-red-box"></div>
          <img src="images/home_support.png">
        </div>
        <h2>we work from home</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
          dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: what do you exactly want to do? If you can show what type of page you are building.

Comment: @Deepakgupta hey, sorry for that, made some changes in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

keep the `img` tag inside `div.small-red-box`. position absolute is not needed in this case. so I have removed it from CSS.

```css
    #Why_choose {
      height: 100%;
      background: #141414;
    }

    .wrap_Container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 3.5rem;
      margin-bottom: 2rem;
    }

    .wrap_Container div {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .wrap_Container>div {
      height: 100%;
    }


    #Why_choose h1 {
      color: white;
      font-size: 3.5rem;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #Why_choose h2 {
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      width: 50%;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    #Why_choose p {
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: 1rem;
      line-height: 1rem;
      width: 60%;
    }

    #Why_choose img {
      width: 20%;

    }

    .Why_heading {
      position: relative;
      height: 25vh;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .Why_heading h1 {

      top: 20%;
    }

    .big-box {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    #Why_choose .small-red-box {
      color: white;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      z-index: 999;
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<section id="Why_choose">
    <div class="Why_heading">
      <h1>Why choose Snap Smile Veneers?</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap_Container">

      <div class="invisible">
        <div class="big-box">
          <div class="small-red-box">
            <img src="images/invisible.png">
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2>we invisible</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
          dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="comfortable">
        <div class="big-box">
          <div class="small-red-box">
            <img src="images/comfortable.png">
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2>we comfortable</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
          dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="workHome">
        <div class="big-box">
          <div class="small-red-box">
            <img src="images/home_support.png">
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2>we work from home</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
          dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Yes, this worked. Can you please explain what the problem was?  Also, when I position the img as absolute, the height and width of the images becomes 0.

Comment: @SahilSingh can you please upvote this post and select it as a solution.